# Is wrong salutation by editor in email reply considerable?

Tags: paper-submission, editors

I sent a research paper to one of the reputed journals through email to the editor.

I used the salutation *Dear editor*  and didn't specify anything about my academic position either in email or in my research paper.

In response to my email, the editor replied to me as *Dear professor*.  I am thinking whether to reply to the email again saying that I am not a professor or not to reply. Is it considerable? Since I am a beginner to this publication stuff, I can't figure out the etiquette of email.

Comment: When I was a PhD student, in the beginning I corrected editors "I don't have a Dr.-titel", but after a while I gave up, for it had no effect.

Comment: Time for a professional "footer" in your email correspondence? Although there is still a chance that this will be ignored, esp. if you don't mention any titles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to send a correction immediately. The editor is most used to dealing with professors, it seems. However, in a future correspondence, you can add a note that you are not yet a professor or that you are studying for a degree, or something similar.

It isn't really a big concern, but you can easily make it a bit more explicit in the future.

Comment: The editor is playing safe: if you really were a professor, you might be offended if the editor addressed you as a mere Mr. On the same basis I have been addressed as "Your Excellency" when attending governmental conferences in foreign countries.

Answer (score 15):

It's very common for editors and such people to address unknown researchers as "Professor" or "Dr" without checking that they actually hold such a position.

It doesn't mean anything; just ignore it.  There is no point in replying.

Answer (score 4):

The editor has uptitled you to avoid the possibility of offence. There's absolutely no need to reply nor to ever correct the editor, that just causes the editor additional work.

<sub>Personally, I would never write *Dear editor*. I'd look-up the editor's name. If I knew them, then I'd just use their first name, otherwise, I'd look-up their title and use their title and family name.</sub>